# Application is no longer saving and kCGErrorFailure errors in Console

Tags: cocoa, macos

I've had two users of my application write in with a very strange saving issue. After some time working with the application (it's a document based Cocoa application), the application stops allowing to save the document and the "Save" and "Save as…" main menu items are grayed out. Opening new documents apparently still works, however they come up with a blank canvas.
I asked both users to check Console.app and those are the lines they found:

First user:

```
<Error>: kCGErrorFailure: _CGSBindWindowBacking: cannot map backing data shmem
<Error>: kCGErrorFailure: _CGSLockWindow: Unable to lock window
```

Second user:

```
kCGErrorIllegalArgument: CGSShapeWindow
kCGErrorFailure: Set a breakpoint @ CGErrorBreakpoint() to catch errors as they are logged.
<Error>: kCGErrorIllegalArgument: CGSShapeWindow
<Error>: kCGErrorFailure: Set a breakpoint @ CGErrorBreakpoint() to catch errors as they are logged.
<Error>: kCGErrorIllegalArgument: CGSShapeWindow
kCGErrorIllegalArgument: CGSShapeWindow
```

I tried my best to reproduce this issue, but without luck. I'm slowly running out of ideas what might cause this issue. Does anyone have any idea what is going on? Memory issue?

Comment: Those are errors from the Core Graphics, presumably from the window server. Do you perform fancy things with the windows? They are very strange errors unless you talk directly to the window server... like rotating the window in 3d using an undocumented API. It might be worth asking your users if they have some strange utilities on their machines.

Comment: I'm not doing any transforms with the Window (besides resizing it). The app is also free from private API. I'll check with the users to see if they have any input managers or similar tools installed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sadly never really found a solution for this problem. Even had an Apple engineer look into this issue via a DTS. The work around that made this issue disappear was keeping images in a temp folder and only loading them into memory when needed. This greatly reduced my memory food print and made the issue go away.